# Python BSoup doesn't find hidden elements, problems with Selenium as alternative

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Hey I asked a similar question before and from what I've learned BSoup doesn't find what I'm searching for because the element is hidden.
For context I find FancyCompLabel when I have the cursor above Rathberger and examine the html code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

cclass=soup.find("div",class_="fancyCompLabel")
print(cclass)
```

It seems like Selenium could be a fix but I have really big problems implementing it.
heres what i tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

import requests


# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')


cclass=soup.find_all("div",class_="fancyCompLabel")
print(cclass)
```

Comment: Which element is `searchalotResultHeader` in UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 There are two "Accept cookies" modals, one of them is inside an iframe. You need to accept both and to stitch the the iframe of the seconds one.

2 You will need for your elements to become present in DOM after you accept the cookies.

I've managed to accomplish this with Selenium.

**Solution**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
#wd.switch_to.default_content()  # you do not need to switch to default content because iframe is closed already
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fancyCompLabel")

for p in results:
    print(p.text)
```

Result:

```
Rathberger GmbH
Deschberger Metall- und Blechbearbeit...
Anant GmbH
Gröbmer GmbH
Berma Plaatwerk BV
Punzonado y Láser METALKOR S.L.
Blankart AG - Werkzeugbau + Fertigung
Goodwill Precision Machinery (German ...
Bechtold GmbH
PMT GmbH
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot its working for me as well ! followup question if it is not too much too ask: how do i access the links which are in the fancycomplabel part (e.g. https://www.techpilot.de/servlets/supplier/perfect_profile.jsp?lngCode=de&ckey=A4gxuEGikU16YXWt6RMd)

Comment: I saw this question is already answered. I was happy to help you. Good luck with your learning.